# What induces the seizure-like movements caused by Pirs?

Tags: sufism

> Pir... is a title for a Sufi master or spiritual guide equally used in the nath tradition. They are also referred to as a Hazrat or Shaikh, which is Arabic for Old Man. The title is often translated into English as "saint" and could be interpreted as "Elder". In Sufism a Pir's role is to guide and instruct his disciples on the Sufi path.  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pir_(Sufism)))

I've seen many videos of what I think are Sufi gatherings, where the people are in near synchronous movements and are chanting/singing or in the act of dhikr. I'd see certain individuals go up to the Pir and touch them, or be touched by them, and this results in the sudden convulsion. What induces these convulsion?

Comment: Pir, what is that?

Comment: in the Indo-Pak region, when pir (Sufi Sheik) gets seizures/convulsions while he/she sits for the spiritual communication. During the event, the friendly angels (or donno who) pass them knowledge which they're seeking. With that knowledge they 'guide' their fellow people @AmericanMuslim

Comment: Do you mean to say they get Wahi like Prophets???

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, the pirs are not as in the past.  Not all, but some of them are on right path of Islam. Pirs are the spiritual mentors who connect one's heart to Allah almighty through dhiker asn wadaifs. When pupils do dhiker in front of their pir, pir give spiritual benefits.  To them it's spirituality. One must have to find kamil pir and do bayat on his hands. But the condition is: pir must be kamil. A kamil pir is one who connects your hearts to Allah and make spiritual changes in his pupils.